# Constructing a class within another class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, pygame

I am working on my game, and have made a level class, but  my parselevel() method will not let me parse the level, because of "Block" not being a global variable (Block is my block class).

How would I do this? Could I just pass Block and Player to the parseLevel method?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\GitHub\ShipGame\level.py", line 3, in <module>
    from entity import *
  File "C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\GitHub\ShipGame\entity.py", line 5, in <module>
    from blocks import *
  File "C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\GitHub\ShipGame\blocks.py", line 4, in <module>
    from level import *
  File "C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\GitHub\ShipGame\level.py", line 4, in <module>
    from blocks import Block
ImportError: cannot import name Block
```

My code:

```
import pygame

from entity import *
from blocks import *

# Holds the level layout in a list of strings.
levelMap = [
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WX                 W",
"W                  W",
"W             P    W",
"W                  W",
"W                  W",
"W                  W",
"W                  W",
"W                  W",
"W                  W",
"W                  W",
"W                  W",
"W   P              W",
"W                  W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
]

class Level(object):

    def __init__(self, levelMap):
        self.levelMap = levelMap

    def parseLevel(self):
        x = 144
        y = 0
        for row in self.levelMap:
            for col in row:
                if col == "W":
                    Block((x, y))
                if col =="P":
                    Port((x, y))
                if col == "X":
                    player = Player((x, y), 1, "Player1", 1, 0)
                x += 32
            y += 32
            x = 144

level = Level(levelMap)
level.parseLevel()
```

Comment: Are `Block` and `Port` in the same file as `Level`?? I'm guessing they are being imported with `from entity import *` and
`from blocks import *` correct ?

Comment: @jramirez you are correct, they are from the blocks.py file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traceback shows that you have a *circular import* problem. When you have a statement `from foo import *`, Python has to finish loading `foo` right away (so that it can work out all the imported names). But this means that:

1. since `level.py` executes `from entity import *`, `entity` must be loaded before `level`;
2. since `entity.py` executes `from blocks import *`, `blocks` must be loaded before `entity`;
3. since `blocks.py` executes `from level import *`, `level` must be loaded before `blocks`.

Obviously this can't work!

What you really ought to do is reorganize your code so that each module doesn't need to know about all the others. (For example, why do `blocks` need to know about `level`?)

But if you are having trouble with that, you can get things working by breaking the circle, for example by writing `import level` instead of `from level import *`. Obviously you'll then have to write `level.foo` instead of `foo`, but that should be easy.

(This works because `import foo` doesn't need `foo` to have finished loading yet.)

See [this entry in the Python FAQ](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module) for more about circular imports.

Comment: Thanks! I cannot figure out why blocks needs to know about level, so I removed that, also, I am going to use from player import Player, so that I don't have to initialize everything, on that end

Comment: `from player import Player` has to finish loading the `player` module (so that the `Player` class has been defined), so that can also lead to circular imports.